# Applying an effect to a SKScene is that expensive?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I am developing a game using SpriteKit. In response to the user getting a bonus, I would like to flash the screen 3 times while the play action continues. By flashing I am inverting the scene colors, but I am open to use other effect.

I have tried to use a CIFilter on the scene, but the frame rate dropped from 60 fps to 13 fps, making the game unplayable.

I have tried to use the CIFilter on the whole scene, by doing this

```
CIFilter * (^invert)(void) = ^ {

  CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
  [filter setDefaults];
  return filter;

};
```

and then changing the scene

```
self.filter = invert();
self.shouldEnableEffects = YES;
```

I am a long time user of Cocos2D. I did this kind of effect on another app of mine developed with Cocos2D in the past and it had barely no impact on the frame rate compared to this miserable frame rate using SpriteKit.

I have tried to apply the effect just to the character that represents the user, that is barely 100x100 pixels. The frame rate dropped from 60 to 30fps... better but the game is also unplayable.

Any way to do this or to achieve some impressive brief effect to the whole screen as the play evolves?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you use images and run animation sequence when the user receives the bonus. That way you can preserve the frame integrity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a game where i flash the screen and the following piece of code runs smoothly, you can try it out and repeat the action as per your need :)

```
// Flash background if contact is detected
        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{
            self.backgroundColor = [SKColor redColor];
        }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05], [SKAction runBlock:^{
            self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blueColor];
        }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]] count:4], [SKAction runBlock:^{
            //Do anything additional you wan to run during flash period
        }]]] withKey:@"flash"];
```

Comment: you are running an action on the scene?

Comment: I love Apple documentation: this is the doc talking about SKAction: *Overview - An SKAction object is an action that is executed by a node in the scene (SKScene).* ... a **node** in the **scene**, not by the scene.

Comment: anyway, it does nothing for me.

Comment: So in your case.. Make a node of the background.. And run the action on the node... I guess it should work then also

Comment: No, the problem was that I already had that node that was covering the background color. Instead what I did is to change the alpha of that node to 0.5 and to 1.0, so it would reveal the bg color behind. This is brilliant! You are a genius! THANKS!!!!!!!